# Exporting style sheets from InDesign 5.5

Tags: fonts, typography, export

Is there a way to export style sheets from InDesign 5.5? Even a list of style sheets that can be printed or exported to Word will be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Quark Convert? ;-) In InDesign these are called "Paragraph Styles".

This functionality is not built into InDesign, but it can be done using scripting. In fact, it *has* been done; see, for example, http://indesignsecrets.com/print-out-style-sheet-specs.php.

The download link gives you a .zip file. Extract it, which will give you a folder called 'TSRC2' (when on Windows you will see a useless "_MacOSX" system folder as well). The folder contains a PDF with instructions, a Javascript, and a helper file. *Follow the instructions in the PDF* and you're good to go. (... the emphasis is because I did not and, surprisingly, it did not work.)

Comment: Haha! You got me. I'm an old Quark user! Thanks for this but I have already tried it and couldn't get it to work. Once the files are moved to the scripts folder - how do you run the script? I am running 5.5 and this script is for CS2 so I thought this might be why it's not working.

Comment: In the comments below the article it is said that it works for CS5.5 (and even all the way up to CC). The usual way of running a script is to locate it in the Scripts panel and then double-click it.